# How to read and write to an existing json file using webapi in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to read and write data to an existing JSON fil using an ASP.NET Web API. And then will consume this API in an ASP.NET MVC application.

JSON file:

```
{
    "Students": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Ravi",
  "department": "IT"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Raj",
  "department": "hr"
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "avi",
  "department": "it"
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "rome",
  "department": "HR"
},
{
  "id":5,
  "name": "virat",
  "department": "HR"
},
{
  "id":6 ,
  "name": "Tushar",
  "department": "RM" 
} 
   ]
  }
```

Classes:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Department { get; set; }
}

public class Students
{
    public List<Student> students { get; set; }
}
```

`ApiController` is getting data from an existing JSON file. If there is any another way do let me know:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class StudentsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("JSONFile")]
    public IEnumerable<Students> Getdata()
    {
        var webclient = new WebClient();
        var json = webclient.DownloadString("C:/Users/tanmay_pawar/source/repos/CRUDAPI/CRUDAPI/output.json");
        var student = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Students>(json);
        yield return student;       
    }
}
```

Using this I'm able to fetch the data from the file. But how can I add new data using post method not able to get it.

Comment: Using `WebClient` to access local file is an interesting approach.

Comment: @GuruStron Also used StreamReader it also works fine.

Comment: I will leave small hints - `File.ReadAllText` and `File.WriteAllText`. Though it's worth mentioning that reading and writing same file in threaded environment like ASP should be done with caution for obvious reasons.

Comment: @GuruStron I'm not getting the exact logic about using File.WriteAllText to add data to my JSON file using webapi. Can you please help ?.